# Launch a android.app.fragment in support.v4.fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I have two fragments in my viewpager: An android.app.fragment and a support.v4.app.fragment.I know that viewpager does not support a android.app.fragment.So is there any way to launch a android.app.Fragment from a support.v4.app.fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can call getActivity() from your support.v4.app.fragment and then call .getFragmentManager() instead of .getSupportFragmentManager() and then .add() or .replace()

BUT

I suggest you to use support.v4.app.fragment for all of your fragment and use an AppCompatActivity for your activity.